# Laravel 5.2 PHPunit form submit create new record

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5

I have the following code. 
Login user and validation works, returns true.

The problem is seePageIs, it returns an error. But after posting the respons has to go to company lister page. So if i change the ->seePageIs('admin/company') to ->seePageIs('admin/company/create') it works.

What's wrong?

Error:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :'http://localhost/admin/company'
Actual   :'http://localhost/admin/company/create'
```

Test:

```
public function testExample()
{
    $this->be(User::find(4));
    $rules = array(
        'companyname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    );

    $data = [
        'companyname' => 'aa',
        'email' => 'aaaa@aa.nl']
    ;

    $v = $this->app['validator']->make( $data, $rules);

    $this->visit('admin/company/create')
        ->press('Create')
        ->assertTrue($v->passes())
        ->seePageIs('admin/company');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your code very well and your question, but maybe it is this line:

```
$this->visit('admin/company/create')
     ->press('Create')
     ->assertTrue($v->passes())
     ->seePageIs('admin/company/create');
```

I just changed the line `seePageIs()` to add **create** at the end. Maybe that is the problem?

Try it.

If not, can you show your code for assertEquals(...)... Thanks!

**EDIT #2**
Hi there Bas; based on your comments and what I think you are trying to do:
If after creating the company, then you want to check it, then you probably need to do this instead:

```
$this->visit('admin/company')
     ->seePageIs('admin/company');
```

Which just goes to the company page an verifies that is the correct page.

Comment: Hi, that works, only is de redirect in my store method to the admin/company

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Can you explain better? Did I answer the question - then it should be up arrow.

Comment: Well if i post the form normally it redirects to admin/company but now i have to setup seePageIs to admin/company/create, or is seePageIs not the redirect?

Comment: Ah, I see what that is now. I use Symfony and Mink, which is a bit different. If you look at [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#application-testing), I see that `->visit` means "go to that page", and '`->seePageIs` means that is the page you should get to (or redirect to). So I think the answer above is correct.

Comment: Exactly, if i use seePageIs('admin/company') then i am getting the error, but that is the correct redirect page. So after creating a company it has to redirect to admin/company but then i am getting that error above.

Comment: I edited my post Bas. Take a look and see if that helps or not.